# Trying to understand Laravel Eloquent relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I am a complete Laravel n00b trying to get my head around how the Eloquent relationship model works. Of course, I could write "raw" SQL using the provided Laravel facilitation of that approach to meet my goals (along with joins across at least two additional tables in this case). But what I want is to fully understand the Eloquent relationship model so that I can write far more elegant/compact code. I am hoping you guys can help me in achieving that goal.

Considering the following diagram depicting an existing set of Laravel Eloquent relationships, what would your most elegant solution be to satisfy the two given functions, `bookingRequestsByArtist($artist_id)` and `bookingRequestsByAdmin($admin_id)` and why?

[image: eloquent_relationship_diagram]

Comment: Left column has something wrong in it. hasManyThrough implies another table. Unless the relationship is Artist hasManyThrough EventBookingRequest (which simply means Artist hasMany X and X hasMAny EventBookingRequest)

Answer (score 0):

On the left side,
assuming the relationships are:

- `Artist` hasMany `EventBookings`
- `EventBookings` hasMany `EventBookingRequests`

**This implies `Artist` hasManyThrough `EventBookingRequests`.**

If you define that relationship in the `Artist` model, then the function becomes trivial.

```
# Artist model
public function event_booking_requests()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(EventBookingRequests::class, EventBookings::class/*, all the extra parameters if your models do not conform to laravel's naming conventions */);
}
```

```
// Eager loading here is optional
return Artist::select('id')
    ->findOrFail($artist_id)
    ->event_booking_requests;
```

---

On the right side, similarly:

- `Agent` hasMany `EventBookings`
- `EventBookings` hasMany `EventBookingRequests`

**This implies `Agent` hasManyThrough `EventBookingRequests`.**

```
# Agent model
public function event_booking_requests()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(EventBookingRequests::class, EventBookings::class/*, all the extra parameters if your models do not conform to laravel's naming conventions */);
}
```

```
// Eager loading here is NOT optional
return Agent::select('id')
    ->whereHas('admins', fn($admin) => $admin->where('id', $admin_id))
    ->with('event_booking_requests')
    ->get()
    ->map->event_booking_requests;
```